# Return only one field from MongoDB query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose my document looks like this

```
{
    "_id": 2,
    "Name": "Abcd",
    "Connected": [1,3]
}
```

Now, I want to retrieve the array `[1,3]` via the `_id` or `Name`. The purpose is to save this array into a JavaScript array.

Hence I tried using `db.myCollection.find({"_id":2},{"Connected":1})` but it return a document again moreover with `_id` still there like this

```
{ "_id" : 2, "Connected" : [ 1, 3 ] }
```

How can I retrieve only that array?

Comment: You get the document back, just use `document.Connected` to get the array...

Comment: @LucaKiebel `db.myCollection.find({"_id":2},{"Connected":1}).Connected` is this what you meant. But I don't get any result.

Comment: Is that find method synchronous? What mongo library are you using?

Comment: @LucaKiebel I am not using any mongo library. I am putting the queries into a javascript file and then running mongo shell via `mongo myDb < jsFile.js`

Comment: I see that you need to exclude the `_id` field explicitly, in the projection. Also, note that, the `find` method return  a _cursor_. Cursor has methods to extract the required data. Optionally, `findOne` returns single document. To retrieve the array field only, on the extracted document and use the `.Connected` on it.

Comment: @prasad_ thanks. doing `arr = db.coll.find(...).toArray()` and then `arr[0].Connected` return the required result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can optionally remove the ID from your result, by setting it to `0` in the projection:

```
db.myCollection.find({"_id":2},{"Connected":1, "_id":0})
```

The ID field is the only field that can be excluded in projections while other fields are included.

If you want to get the `Connected` field directly, you can use `findOne`:

```
db.myCollection.findOne({"_id":2}, {"Connected":1, "_id":0}).Connected
```

Comment: Thanks. Although your assumption of doing `.Connected` on the returned Document was correct, it probably doesn't work on the cursor directly. Doing `toArray()` first is what was needed.

Comment: The second query works but only in the `mongosh` shell and not in `mongo`. In `mongo`, one still has to first do `arr = db.coll.find(...).toArray()` and then `arr[0].Connected`